# Update Manager is not working in Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: 13.10, update-manager

My Update Manager is not working when I am trying to update the system. Even if it opens it crashes. When I try to to run from terminal it shows an error message which is as follows:

```
*dinse@dinse-G41T-M7:~$ update-manager synaptic
(update-manager:2086): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets.css:93:20: Not using units is deprecated. Assuming 'px'.
(update-manager:2086): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets.css:199:20: Not using units is deprecated. Assuming 'px'.
(update-manager:2086): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets.css:220:16: Not using units is deprecated. Assuming 'px'.
(update-manager:2086): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets.css:220:20: Not using units is deprecated. Assuming 'px'.
(update-manager:2086): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets.css:233:20: Not using units is deprecated. Assuming 'px'.
(update-manager:2086): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets.css:286:22: Not a valid image
(update-manager:2086): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets.css:290:22: Not a valid image
(update-manager:2086): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets.css:307:20: Not using units is deprecated. Assuming 'px'.
(update-manager:2086): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets.css:395:19: 'fg_color' is not a valid color name
(update-manager:2086): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets.css:536:20: Not using units is deprecated. Assuming 'px'.
(update-manager:2086): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets.css:587:19: Not using units is deprecated. Assuming 'px'.
(update-manager:2086): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets.css:951:19: Not using units is deprecated. Assuming 'px'.
(update-manager:2086): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets.css:1017:20: Not using units is deprecated. Assuming 'px'.
(update-manager:2086): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets.css:1027:20: Not using units is deprecated. Assuming 'px'.
(update-manager:2086): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets.css:1027:22: Not using units is deprecated. Assuming 'px'.
(update-manager:2086): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets.css:1055:14: Not using units is deprecated. Assuming 'px'.
(update-manager:2086): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets.css:1730:20: Not using units is deprecated. Assuming 'px'.
(update-manager:2086): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets.css:1747:21: Not using units is deprecated. Assuming 'px'.
(update-manager:2086): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets.css:1763:20: Not using units is deprecated. Assuming 'px'.
(update-manager:2086): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets.css:1809:16: Not using units is deprecated. Assuming 'px'.
(update-manager:2086): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets.css:1809:18: Not using units is deprecated. Assuming 'px'.
(update-manager:2086): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets.css:1809:20: Not using units is deprecated. Assuming 'px'.
(update-manager:2086): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets.css:1812:20: Not using units is deprecated. Assuming 'px'.
(update-manager:2086): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets.css:1825:16: Not using units is deprecated. Assuming 'px'.
(update-manager:2086): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets.css:1825:18: Not using units is deprecated. Assuming 'px'.
(update-manager:2086): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets.css:1825:20: Not using units is deprecated. Assuming 'px'.
(update-manager:2086): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets.css:1830:23: Not using units is deprecated. Assuming 'px'.
(update-manager:2086): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets.css:1839:23: Not using units is deprecated. Assuming 'px'.
(update-manager:2086): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets.css:1853:11: Not using units is deprecated. Assuming 'px'.
(update-manager:2086): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets.css:1925:14: Not using units is deprecated. Assuming 'px'.
(update-manager:2086): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets-backdrop.css:27:20: Not using units is deprecated. Assuming 'px'.
(update-manager:2086): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets-backdrop.css:106:20: Not using units is deprecated. Assuming 'px'.
(update-manager:2086): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets-backdrop.css:131:4: not a number
(update-manager:2086): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets-backdrop.css:152:4: not a number
(update-manager:2086): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets-backdrop.css:171:4: not a number
(update-manager:2086): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets-backdrop.css:201:20: Not using units is deprecated. Assuming 'px'.
(update-manager:2086): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets-backdrop.css:381:19: Not using units is deprecated. Assuming 'px'.
(update-manager:2086): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets-backdrop.css:393:19: Not using units is deprecated. Assuming 'px'.
(update-manager:2086): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets-backdrop.css:738:20: Not using units is deprecated. Assuming 'px'.
(update-manager:2086): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets-backdrop.css:814:20: Not using units is deprecated. Assuming 'px'.
(update-manager:2086): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets-backdrop.css:830:20: Not using units is deprecated. Assuming 'px'.
(update-manager:2086): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets-backdrop.css:846:20: Not using units is deprecated. Assuming 'px'.
(update-manager:2086): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gnome-panel.css:92:20: Not using units is deprecated. Assuming 'px'.
(update-manager:2086): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: nautilus.css:14:18: Not using units is deprecated. Assuming 'px'.
(update-manager:2086): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: nautilus.css:14:20: Not using units is deprecated. Assuming 'px'.
(update-manager:2086): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: nautilus.css:118:20: Not using units is deprecated. Assuming 'px'.
(update-manager:2086): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: nautilus.css:123:20: Not using units is deprecated. Assuming 'px'.
(update-manager:2086): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: nautilus.css:148:20: Not using units is deprecated. Assuming 'px'.
(update-manager:2086): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: nautilus.css:154:20: Not using units is deprecated. Assuming 'px'.
(update-manager:2086): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: nautilus.css:159:21: Junk at end of value
(update-manager:2086): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: nautilus.css:175:20: Not using units is deprecated. Assuming 'px'.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/update-manager", line 114, in <module>
    app = UpdateManager(data_dir, options)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/UpdateManager/UpdateManager.py", line 113, in __init__
    self.options and self.options.use_proposed)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/UpdateManager/MetaReleaseGObject.py", line 44, in __init__
    MetaReleaseCore.__init__(self, useDevelopmentRelease, useProposed)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/UpdateManager/Core/MetaRelease.py", line 90, in __init__
    self.flavor_name = get_ubuntu_flavor_name()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/UpdateManager/Core/utils.py", line 447, in get_ubuntu_flavor_name
    pkg = get_ubuntu_flavor_package(cache=cache)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/UpdateManager/Core/utils.py", line 437, in get_ubuntu_flavor_package
    cache = apt.Cache()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apt/cache.py", line 105, in __init__
    self.open(progress)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apt/cache.py", line 154, in open
    self._list.read_main_list()
SystemError: E:Malformed line 52 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list (dist parse)*
```

Comment: Could you be a little more explicit? Any errors? Have you tried running it from a terminal to see if there are any errors there? As it stands nobody can help you. Please edit your question to include more information about the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your update manager needs updated ;)

Try

```
    sudo apt-get update
```

then

```
    sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how yours is (was?) misbehaving, but mine was acting up earlier today (just a title bar with nothing else, had to force-quit it), and this is how I fixed it:

```
sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/* -vf
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Works fine now.